# Django uses default reset form instead of my Html

Tags: python, html, django

I'm new in Django. Have

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('login/', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.logout_then_login, name='logout'),
    path('reset/', auth_views.password_reset, name='reset'),
    path('reset/done', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

in my urls.py and have password_reset_done.html and other files at accounts/templates/registration. But Django uses deafult form for reset, but use my login.html from the same directory. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don’t want to use the default registration/password_reset.html template, you can include a third parameter in the urlpattern which is a Python dictionary like so

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password.html'}),
```

Or if you are using templates/registration/.... your templates are render by default.
But look maybe you have a problem with your urls,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout),
    url(r'^', include('mysite.urls')),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete),
]
```

Look de diference you write `path` not `url`

Hope it Helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but still does not work. When i try to add third urlpattern it cant find my html. URLS are the same as login, which works properly. Maybe something wrong with my settings?
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

Comment: needed to use regular template folder and your advice:
    path('reset/done', auth_views.password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'password_reset_done.html'},
         name='password_reset_done'),
It works now! Thank you!

Comment: If you have an app created into a project, maybe you have to put your templates dir into your app, Project\app\templates . But if you use this urls from root, your syntax 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], is correct, the problems maybe on other place...keeping looking.